# How to find out the package name of an app on Admob?

Tags: android, admob

Yesterday, I added one of the Android apps on my Admob account but I don't remember the package name (It's not published on the store yet).

Here's the screenshot of the app settings page on the Admob console:

[image]

So, where can I find out the package name of this app and is it possible to use this App's ad unit in a different app altogether (earlier I could do that but recently things have changed so I'm not sure of it)

Comment: now we didn't need to add package name while creating new app in admob. Only they are asking name if its not available on play store. If it is live on play store than you can link in admob and may package name will display. So as you said your app is not live, so there will be no package name.

Comment: @pratikvekariya Ahh, I thought I entered a package name while adding the app. Thanks for your comment. You can write it down in the answer box.

Comment: no I'm sure if app is not live than they are not asking for package name, Just 2 days before I created new app.

Comment: @pratikvekariya Thanks, I just confirmed that too. They don't really ask for the package name. I should either delete this post altogether or you can write it as the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: okay i'm writing answer, reputation will be increased if you make it write :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, when you add an app to your Admob account, you don't need to provide a package name, only the app name. Once your app goes live on the store, you can link it to the Admob using its URL.

However, if your app is already live on the store, you can simply add it to your Admob account using the store URL.

Since, your app is not live, you don't have to worry about the package name.